# Algebra question: unbiased estimator of variance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, variance

I've been racking my brain over what I suspect should be a simple question. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Examples) offers this explanation of why the sample mean is a biased estimator of the population mean:

\begin{aligned}\operatorname {E} [S^{2}]=\operatorname {E} \left[{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-{\overline {X}}\right)^{2}\right]=\operatorname {E} {\bigg [}{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\big (}(X_{i}-\mu )-({\overline {X}}-\mu ){\big )}^{2}{\bigg ]}=\\
=\operatorname {E} {\bigg [}{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\mu )^{2}-2({\overline {X}}-\mu )(X_{i}-\mu )+({\overline {X}}-\mu )^{2}{\bigg ]}=\\
=\operatorname {E} {\bigg [}{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\mu )^{2}-({\overline {X}}-\mu )^{2}{\bigg ]}=\sigma ^{2}-\operatorname {E} \left[({\overline {X}}-\mu )^{2}\right]<\sigma ^{2}.\end{aligned}

Can anyone please explain to me how we went from $${=\operatorname {E} {\bigg [}\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\mu )^{2}-2({\overline {X}}-\mu )(X_{i}-\mu )+({\overline {X}}-\mu )^{2}{\bigg ]}$$

to:
$${=\operatorname {E} {\bigg [}{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\mu )^{2}-({\overline {X}}-\mu )^{2}{\bigg ]}}$$

I don't see how $**{-2({\overline {X}}-\mu )(X_{i}-\mu )+({\overline {X}}-\mu )^{2}}**$ turned into $-({\overline {X}}-\mu )^{2}$.

Please, help. I know it's simple, but my only math is what I have left over from school. Thanks.

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing (even wrong). It must be made clear that the summation involves more than one term.

Comment: @drhab - It is indeed confusing (and in my experience, summation signs don't get enough brackets in general). However, in this case one can hardly call the notation wrong, I think. Anything that involves an $i$ has to be part of the sum. This means there's only confusion about the last term. But for that one, it doesn't matter whether it's in the sum or not...

Comment: @DaanMichiels I stick to "wrong". This in spite of the fact that it can be guessed what $\sum_i a_i+b_i$ means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}2\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)\left(X_{i}-\mu\right)=2\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\mu\right)=2\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}-n\mu\right]=2n\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{2}$

and

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{2}=n\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{2}$

Subtracting the first from the second you arrive at

$-n\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}-\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{2}$

---

**edit** (route with more oversight)

$\mathbb{E}S^{2}=\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}=\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[X_{i}^{2}-2\overline{X}X_{i}+\overline{X}^{2}\right]$

First do the special case $\mu=0$ and we treat the three terms separately.

Equipped with the knowledge that $\mathbb{E}X_{i}^{2}=\sigma^{2}$
and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=n\overline{X}$ we find:

$\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}X_{i}^{2}=\sigma^{2}$

$\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[-2\overline{X}X_{i}\right]=-2\mathbb{E}\overline{X}^{2}$

$\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\overline{X}^{2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\overline{X}^{2}=\mathbb{E}\overline{X}^{2}$

So addition of these terms leads to $\mathbb{E}S^{2}=\sigma^{2}-\mathbb{E}\overline{X}^{2}$

In the general case define $Y_{i}=X_{i}-\mu$ and realize that $\overline{Y}=\overline{X}-\mu$
so that $X_{i}-\overline{X}=Y_{i}-\overline{Y}$.

Then: $$\mathbb{E}S^{2}=\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\overline{X}\right)^{2}=\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Y_{i}-\overline{Y}\right)^{2}=\sigma^{2}-\mathbb{E}\overline{Y}^{2}=\sigma^{2}-\mathbb{E}\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{2}$$

Comment: Thanks! I would've never come to it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just isolate the relevant part. First, split up the sum.
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left( -2(\overline{X}-\mu)(X_i-\mu) + (\overline{X}-\mu)^2 \right)
= \frac1n \left( -2 (\overline{X} - \mu) \sum_i(X_i - \mu) + \sum_i (\overline{X}-\mu)^2 \right)
$$
Note that $\sum_i X_i = n\overline{X}$. This gives
$$ \frac1n \left( -2 (\overline{X} - \mu) (n\overline{X} - n\mu) + n(\overline{X}-\mu)^2 \right) $$
which is
$$ -2(\overline{X} - \mu)(\overline{X} - \mu) + (\overline{X}-\mu)^2 $$
and that equals $-(\overline{X}-\mu)^2$.

Comment: Thank you, Daan! That was very useful too.